# Meta tags extraction with YQL

Tags: javascript, jquery, xpath, web-scraping, yql

My YQL Query :

```
select * from html where url="http://www.pricetree.com/mobile/nokia-lumia-925-price-8988" and xpath='//meta[@itemprop="lowPrice"]/@content'
```

I'm getting result as null.

Meta tag in HTML source in website :

```
<meta itemprop="lowPrice" content="23,701"/>
```

Is there a way i can fetch the metatag using YQL or any other Jquery/javascript kit

Comment: what if you change quotes: `xpath="//meta[@itemprop='lowPrice']/@content"`?

Comment: that does not work as well.